# vue panzoom увеличение относительно центра экрана

Tags: vue.js

В документации сказано, что panzoom по умолчанию увеличивает ту область, на которой находится курсор, но в моем проекте (без каких-либо настроек в panzoom), увеличение происходит относительно центра экрана.

В чем проблема?

```
<panZoom class="overflow-hidden">
  <items-for-kappa></items-for-kappa>
</panZoom>
```

Answer (score 0):

Причина была в том, что нужно было в компоненте panZoom добавить :options="{transformOrigin: null}"